# How to store secure private keys on a server, that are being used for 'gasless' minting using EIP-712 based messages?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, security, cryptography, secp256k1

NOTE: By 'gasless' I mean that I won't have to mint the tokens for the user, they can mint it themselves provided they have a valid signature.

Hi,

In my NFT (ERC-721) contract, I'm allowing callers to mint via the interface:

```
function mint(bytes calldata signature, uint256 tokenId)
```

The idea is that my backend server will provide eligible users with a signature. The mint function will decrypt that signature and validate that the signer is the expected signer and whether the caller is allowed to mint the tokenId that is passed into the function.

The unsafe way of implementing the backend would be to store the private key of the approved signer on the server. Whenever a user makes a request, the backend will check if they are eligible to make that request and if so, provide them with a signature of a message which allows them to mint a token with that tokenId.

Is there a way to avoid storing the private key on the server whilst also preventing a hacker from generating as many signatures as they want should they get access to my server?

I've looked into HSMs, e.g. AWS CloudHSM, but to me it seems like that won't solve my issue. That's because even if the hacker cannot obtain the signer's private key from the HSM, they can make as many signing calls as they want to the HSM to ultimately mint as many tokens as they want (if they had access to my server).

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm also interested. Did you come up with something? I feel that the existing solutions (e.g. cloudHSM or openzeppelin relayer) hide the private key but force you to use an API key to access it. This makes possible to simply generate new API keys in case of attack, or simply rotate them often, keeping the wallet constant and giving more freedom, yet they don't fully solve the issue.